# Change corner coordinates GEOTIFF

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I have a geotiff and I have the corner coordinates set using `gdal_translate` and the `a_ullr` argument setting out the min/max long/lat. This provides a bounding box for the geotiff to be projected.

But I want this projected different to just a bounding box when displayed as a layer on a map. E.g. see this picture below.

On the left is what the geotiff is, with the corner coordinates defined. But I want each corner to have it's own lat/long defined separately, so you get as shown on the right.

Whats the best way of doing this so it's displayed as so as a layer on a map.

(Using ESPG:4326)

[image]

Comment: Set 4 ground control points with -gcp parameters. If your viewer cannot warp the image on-the-fly (like QGIS can) convert the image into normal north-up geotiff with gdalwarp.